# How many points for statistical significance in design of experiments

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design, latin-hypercube, latin-square

I am running an experiment that includes 27 input data points. The function yields results if we input $2 \leq x \leq 27$ points.
I divide my data points in 9 sets of 3 points each.
Now, I want to prove that if we take 1 data point from each set we get roughly the same results as when using all 27 data points.
This means in total there are $3^9$ input combinations. I made a software that generates such random combinations. How many data points do I need to show this?

Comment: You should refine this question.  If you want to **prove** that a subsample yields "roughly the same" results as the full sample, you have to test all combinations.  If you want to prove that a function of the subsample has a 95% chance of being within X units of the function on the full sample, you might be able to make a statistical argument.  Providing some code would help others understand what you are trying to do.  Also, it is not clear why you tagged this question with latin-hypercube and latin-square.  Are there other requirements you didn't state?

Comment: Yes, I would like to show that a function of the subsample has a 95% chance of being within X units of the function on the full sample. 
The reason I included a latin-hypercube is because the 95% should be the case only where the subsamples are taken one from each of the 9 sets. And I thought I could use latin hpyercube to generate a good variety of which of the three images from each of the 9 sets are used.